upgrading OpenAPI 3.1 causes generator and swagger problem for query parameters
`We tried to upgrade our openapi version from 3.0.3 to 3.1.0.
But we faced issues that swagger ui does not render query parameters as object style.
We use:
<java.version>17</java.version>

<spring.boot.version>3.1.1</spring.boot.version>

<org.springdoc.openapi.version>2.2.0</org.springdoc.openapi.version>

OpenAPI description:
"/v1/rente/auskunft/{annr}": {
    "get": {
        "operationId": "rentenAuskunft",
        "parameters": [
            {
                "in": "path",
                "name": "annr",
                "description": "arbeitnehmernummer",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                }
            },
            {
                "in": "query",
                "style": "deepObject",
                "explode": true,
                "name": "rentenAuskunftParamsDto",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RentenAuskunftParamsDto"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

generator plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId> openapi-generator-maven-plugin </artifactId>
    <version> 7.5.0 </version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id> rente-api </id>
            <goals>
                <goal> generate </goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generatorName> spring </generatorName>
                <library> spring-boot </library>
                <skipIfSpecIsUnchanged> true </skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>
                <generateApis> true </generateApis>
                <generateApiDocumentation> true </generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateApiTests> false </generateApiTests>
                <generateModels> true </generateModels>
                <generateModelDocumentation> false </generateModelDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests> false </generateModelTests>
                <generateSupportingFiles> true </generateSupportingFiles>
                <output> ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources </output>
                <modelPackage> xxx.model </modelPackage>
                <apiPackage> xxx.api </apiPackage>
                <skipValidateSpec> false </skipValidateSpec>
                <typeMappings>
                    <typeMapping> OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime </typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
                <schemaMappings>
                </schemaMappings>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder> main/java </sourceFolder>
                    <useSpringBoot3> true </useSpringBoot3>
                    <validateSpec> false </validateSpec>
                    <interfaceOnly> true </interfaceOnly>
                    <!--Usemodernjava8date/timeapi-->
                    <dateLibrary> java8 </dateLibrary>
                    <!--Enablebeanvalidationusingjavaxvalidationandhibernatevalidator-->
                    <useBeanValidation> true </useBeanValidation>
                    <performBeanValidation> true </performBeanValidation>
                    <openApiNullable> false </openApiNullable>
                    <!--suppress<additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Builder@lombok.NoArgsConstructor@lombok.AllArgsConstructor</additionalModelTypeAnnotations><generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs>false</generatedConstructorWithRequiredArgs><!-Placerequiredparametersfirstinmodels-->
                    <sortModelPropertiesByRequiredFlag> true </sortModelPropertiesByRequiredFlag>
                    <sortParamsByRequiredFlag> true </sortParamsByRequiredFlag>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

generated code:
@RequestMapping 
(method = RequestMethod.GET,value ="/v1/rente/auskunft/{annr}",
produces = {"application/json"})
default
ResponseEntity<RentenAuskunftResponse>rentenAuskunft(
@Parameter
(name ="annr",description ="arbeitnehmernummer",required =true,in = ParameterIn.PATH)
@PathVariable("annr") Long annr,
@NotNull @Parameter(name ="rentenAuskunftParamsDto",required =true,in = ParameterIn.QUERY)
@Valid
 RentenAuskunftParamsDto rentenAuskunftParamsDto)

We tried to use deepObject style but it does not take affect.
Also using nullable does not take affect.

According to the current documentation for the OpenAPI Generator as of version 7.7.0, OpenApi 3.1 is currently only in beta support.  This likely means that some features of OpenAPI 3.1 aren't fully supported.  If your schema was working with the generator prior to upgrading to 3.1, it may be best to stay with 3.0.3.

Thank you tbatch. I just want to be sure if these are not supported or I have any configuration issue.
